# Who is hosting my Git repository and it's URL

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

We're using git in our organization but how do I know if we are using GitHub or BitBucket or something else? And how do I find respective web URL (to browse the repo in a browser like GitHub).

Comment: Check the remote?

Comment: just curious. why downvote?

Comment: I downvoted because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to run `git remote get-url origin` while in a repo folder - this will show you the URL that Git uses to communicate with that specific repo.

If the URL looks like `https://username@host/path/to/repo` then you should be able to get to the Web version of the repo at `https://host/path/to/repo` (the git remote URL without the username). If the URL doesn't include that `username@` part then that's also fine.

If the URL looks like `git@host:path/to/repo` or `username@host:path/to/repo` then the Web version should be available at `https://host/path/to/repo`.

Of course, the specific host for that specific repo may not have a Web offering, but github.com, bitbucket.org, gitlab.com, and several others do. If the URL does not include one of those domains, then you may just need to try it in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

From inside your repo, try checking out for the remote, if configured by using the command

`git remote -v`

You'll get an idea of where it is being pushed to/ pulled from.

If it is of the form `git@github.com` or similar it is self-explanatory.